# 1A Voltage Regulator - Maximum or output?

Tags: voltage, voltage-regulator

I want to design a circuit that has 12V1A output from a battery. I am using a 12V voltage regulator

Do I want a 12V 3A Regulator or 12V 1A regulator?

If a 12V 1A voltage regulator gives me a better dropout voltage, should I use that?

The current is dependent on what the load will draw, right?

Sorry if its a bit of a simple question, but even searching I can't find the answer, it just gives me different questions.

Thanks

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to achieve here. Are you trying to get regulated output from a battery?

Comment: What are the minimum and maximum battery voltages and the minimum and maximum load voltages and currents?

Comment: for ur question....both are will work.....add any other constraints which will distinguish in between them..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My awnser assumes that your battery can provide enough current / voltage.

You can use both voltage regulators, as the load only draws the current it needs. So if your load is drawing 1A constant, you can use any voltage regulator that has a output current of 1A or above. I would choose personally a voltage regulator a bit higher then the circuit draws. (So if the circuit draws 1A I'll choose a voltage regulator of 1.5A or higher) This is just to be sure your voltage regulator can provide the current that is needed.

Choosing between a low drop and a non low drop voltage regulator depends on the battery you are going to use. If your battery is like 15V a normal voltage regulator should do. Be sure to check the datasheet for the minimum input voltage when you are going to regulate it to 12V.

Comment: Thank you. In that case I will go for the 3A regulator. I have 14.8V battery (4x3.7V cells) so that should be all good, thanks :)